# Video/Image maximize symbol in ascii?

Tags: html, css, ascii

So, is there a maximize symbol in ascii that I can use in my HTML document? I really want to refrain from using a picture..

Example below:

[image]

That is basically the symbol I am looking for. Couldn't find anything about it elsewhere..

Comment: Have you tried? http://graphemica.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ready to use Google Icons

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons">fullscreen</i>
```

Otherwise, i don't think there's a Symbol like that in the ASCII Table.